# Certain commands in Ssh.Net don't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, putty, ssh.net

I'm new here. I've basically run out of options so i'm hoping somebody can point me in some sort of direction to a page or code suggestions. I'm trying to run scripts on our shell (PuTTY). I can do everything except the unzip and stream commands, is there a certain way to set this up, or are they just not recognized by Ssh.Net? I need to extract a file from our zipFolder.

> I use the `SshClient.RunCommand()` to run `unzip " + <zipFilePath> + " " + <file>` but nothing happens.

If anybody can help me out, that'd be amazing. I have connection set up fine, i can create files, echo into them, copy. It's just the important commands I need. Thank you

Comment: Is `unzip` installed in the 'remote' box?

Comment: yes all the commands are there @pollirrata

Comment: plz check log messag in  /var/log/messages

Answer (score 0):

Mostly putty shell script by default run in home directory of logged in user. So you need to be confirm that zip file exists there. And also the logged in user does have the rights permission.

Comment: i direct with the full file path and i'm an admin user so i know the permissions are there. I'll try to cd into the directory and run the command at the same time, but for now i ended up just making a java program and calling that program to run it. i can't even run a shell script by calling it, so far java call is the only that work. It's not exeactly right, but it's something till i can find the cause of the unzip not working through